# How to auto-hide react-navigation header with scroll down?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

How can I automatically hide a header with a scroll-down action and show the header with a scroll-up action in Android using react-navigation in React Native?

```js
    const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({

      Home: {
        screen: HomeIndexScreen,
      },
      Details: {
        screen: HomeItemScreen,
      }
    },{
      headerLayoutPreset : 'center',
      headerMode: 'float'
    });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47516155/hide-tabnavigators-and-header-on-scroll
this might will help you or you can go for collapsing toolbar

Comment: were you able to solve this problem?